# Assign group id start from 0 and end with 1 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset the following

```
DT <- data.drame(v1 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to create a ID cumulatively stopped at a value of 1.

The ID should be

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dplyr, this will do the trick.

```
DT = data.frame(v1 = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1))

DT %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(rno = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group = ifelse(v1 == 0, NA, rno)) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(group, .direction = "up") %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(v1, ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `ave` :

```
with(DT, ave(v1, c(0, cumsum(v1)[-length(v1)]), FUN = seq_along))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
```

In `dplyr` , we can use `lag` to create groups and assign row number in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% group_by(gr = lag(cumsum(v1), default = 0)) %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
```

and we can use the same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, ID := seq_len(.N), shift(cumsum(v1), fill = 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In dply, if I have an additional group ID and I want to do the above trick by group, can i simply run: DT %>% group_by(group_id,gr = lag(cumsum(v1), default = 0)) %>% mutate(ID = row_number())

Comment: @AegeanT.Wu yes, exactly that should work. A safer option would be `DT %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  group_by(gr = lag(cumsum(v1), default = 0), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) `